# Django дополнительная валидация в serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть модель Books

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_available = models.BoleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
    is_selling = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Сериалайзер

```
class BooksSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = [
            'name',
            'price',
            'is_available',
            'is_selling',
        ]
        validators = [
            RequiredValidator(
                fields=('price')
            )
        ]
```

Подскажите, а как сделать так, что бы validators на цену срабатывал только тогда, когда is_selling = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверено, но если верить докам, то примерно так

```
class BooksSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...
    def validate(self, data):
        if data['is_selling']  != 1:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Цэ заборонено")
        return data
```

Добавлю. В доках DRF значится

```
In DRF, serializer validation is run in a specific, undocumented order

    Field deserialization called (serializer.to_internal_value and field.run_validators)
    serializer.validate_[field] is called for each field.
    Serializer-level validators are called (serializer.run_validation followed by serializer.run_validators)
    Finally, serializer.validate is called to complete validation.
```

Поэтому валидацию цены придется реализовывать самому в validate() или в validate_price

Comment: Данный мето работает. Большое спасибо за помощь )